# CFT dual to a black hole

Tags: quantum-field-theory, gravity, black-holes, ads-cft, holographic-principle

AdS/CFT is famous correspondence between gravity and CFT.

**What one can say about black holes using this correspondence?**

What CFT object correspondent for black hole? For charged black hole? Rotating black hole?

**What kind of information about black hole one can extract from this correspondence?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When a Black Hole is present in a bulk, it gives the background some temperature due to Hawking radiation. Thus a stable spacetime in presence of a generic BH has a fixed tempertature $T$. The dual CFT theory also has thermal states. It has been recently shown that these thermal states have one-to-one correspondence with the Black Hole backgrounds of AdS spacetime. Although for extremal black holes(BH with $T=0$) one must take an appropriate limit. Charged, rotating black holes usually have non-zero temperature and hence the above prescription follows.

Comment: What is differences between different black holes?

Comment: To this answer I would add that charged and spinning black holes have the effect of introducing a chemical potential for the associated symmetry in the boundary theory.

Comment: I think @MannyC 's comment answers Nikita's.

Comment: @MannyC  what kind of information about black hole one can extract from this correspondence?